# Query ArcGIS mapserver REST

Tags: geojson, arcgis-rest-api

I try to download data from the city of Rome with this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON EVC_rome.json "http://services2.arcgis.com/NZMqCJwY3kMjFOqf/arcgis/rest/services/ricarica_elettrica/FeatureServer/0/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON -gt 1000
```

The OSGeo4Q Shell says "unable to open datasource `http://services2.arcgis.com/NZMqCJwY3kMjFOqf/arcgis/rest/services/ricarica_elettrica/FeatureServer/0/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json' with the following drivers."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just taking your url and copying it into the browser I get back:

{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Cannot perform query. Invalid query parameters.","details":["'Invalid field: objectid' parameter is invalid"]}}

So the issue is in your url format.

http://services2.arcgis.com/NZMqCJwY3kMjFOqf/ArcGIS/rest/services/ricarica_elettrica/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds&returnGeometry=true&f=json  works so it's how you are forming your url..

Comment: Great, it works. But now I get this error:"EPSG PCS/GCS code 102100 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?" The spatial reference is stored here `spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}` Any idea how I can select the latestWkid?

Comment: If you look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Projected_coordinate_systems/02r3000000vt000000/ you will see  102100 and 3857 are the same. For the Esri rest service I would just substitute 3857 for 102100 in the URL.  I would test it to see if it's giving you the correct locations,